# C# - Collections - Exercício Enigma

Tags: java, c#, .net, asp

Olá, estava fazendo uma lista de exercício para faculdade e me deparei com este exercício, no qual se tem uma parte do código e ele pede descobrir qual estrutura de código ele pertence.
Ao meu ver, isso parece ser uma fila, porém não consigo entender completamente e comprovar no código, dando um exemplo de uma aplicação. Se alguém puder me ajudar, eu agradeço atenção.

Parte do Código - Exercício Enígma:

```
public void remover() {
        if (!estaVazia()) {
            inicio++;
            qtdeElementos--;
       }
}
```

Qual estrutura refere-se o código mencionado:

a)  Pilha

b)  Fila

c)  Lista simples

d)  Lista duplamente encadeada

e)  Vetor

Answer (score 3):

Matheus, seu entendimento está correto, é um trecho de um algoritmo de implementação de FILA, como você deve saber, o [conceito](https://www.cos.ufrj.br/~rfarias/cos121/filas.html) nos diz:

> São estruturas de dados do tipo FIFO (first-in first-out), onde o
>   primeiro elemento a ser inserido, será o primeiro a ser retirado, ou
>   seja, adiciona-se itens no fim e remove-se do início.

Basicamente as FILAS possuem [duas operações](https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algoritmos_e_Estruturas_de_Dados/Filas):

1. **Enqueue**: inserir um elemento no final da fila.
2. **Dequeue**: remover um elemento do começo da fila.

O trecho do seu código é uma operação **Dequeue**, remoção, e conforme foi mencionado acima, você terá que remover o primeiro elemento por isso `inicio++` e posteriormente a isso você terá que diminuir o tamanho da fila por isso `qtdeElementos--`

Veja seu código completo, em linguagem java, retirado deste [link](https://www.guj.com.br/t/estrutura-fila/338346):

```
import javax.swing.*;

class Fila{
    int inicio;
    int fim;
    int tamanho;
    int qtdeElementos;
    int f[];

    public Fila(){
        inicio = fim = -1;
        tamanho = 100;
        f = new int[tamanho];
        qtdeElementos = 0;
    }

    public boolean estaVazia(){
        if (qtdeElementos == 0){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean estaCheia(){
        if (qtdeElementos == tamanho - 1){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void adicionar(int e){
        if (! estaCheia()){
            if (inicio == -1){
                inicio = 0;
            }
            fim++;
            f[fim] = e;
            qtdeElementos++;
        }
    }

    public void remover(){
        if (! estaVazia() ){
            inicio++;
            qtdeElementos--;
        }
    }

    public void mostrar(){
        String elementos = "";
            for (int i = inicio; i<=fim; i++) {
                elementos += f[i]+ " - ";
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, elementos);
    }
}
```

Se ainda houver alguma dúvida, uma imagem vale mais que mil palavras, veja [as explicações detalhadas aqui](https://www.cos.ufrj.br/~rfarias/cos121/filas.html):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]